# Changing network configuration for all VMs in VirtualBox

Tags: powershell

I've a problem with forceing NAT mode on network cards in all VirtualBox machines. The only solution I have found is to replace the code in the configuration file located in the C:\Users\USER\VirtualBoxVMs\VirtualMachineName\VirtualMachineName.vbox.

Unfortunately, I cannot simply replace these files because each user has different settings (such as the name of the VM)

I have to replace the text in the 
`<Adapter>...<Adapter>` tag. Doing it on one computer for one user is not a problem. I can't deal with the fact that I have to do it with a script on multiple computers for all users. So far, I've managed to do something like this, and I don't know what to do next.

```
$InputFiles = Get-Item "C:\Users\*\VirtualBox VMs\*\*.vbox"

$OldString  = '<Adapter ...various computer-dependent variables...>
        ...
        ...
        </Adapter>'

$NewString  = '<Adapter ...various computer-dependent variables...>
          <NAT/>
        </Adapter>'

$InputFiles | ForEach {
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($OldString,$NewString) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Another complication is that when saving changes, everything is saved in one file for all users, i.e. all settings from all machines on a given computer as one file.

Unfortunately, VB does not store such values in the register, which makes it very difficult. Maybe there is another, easy way?

EDIT: Sample VBox config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
-->
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.15-windows">
  <Machine uuid="{1d96510c-97ce-4671-a1df-3f08c7d2b2c7}" name="TEST" OSType="Windows7_64" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2020-05-04T09:56:34Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{eab23143-54ec-4f7d-822d-a56bf90a58bb}" location="TEST.vdi" format="VDI" type="Normal"/>
      </HardDisks>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/FirstRun" value="yes"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Hardware>
      <CPU>
        <PAE enabled="false"/>
        <LongMode enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="true"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="2048"/>
      <HID Pointing="USBTablet"/>
      <Paravirt provider="Default"/>
      <Display VRAMSize="18"/>
      <VideoCapture fps="25" options="ac_enabled=false"/>
      <RemoteDisplay enabled="false"/>
      <BIOS>
        <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
      </BIOS>
      <USB>
        <Controllers>
          <Controller name="OHCI" type="OHCI"/>
          <Controller name="EHCI" type="EHCI"/>
        </Controllers>
      </USB>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="MACAddress" cable="true" type="82540EM">
          <NAT/>
        </Adapter>
      </Network>
      <AudioAdapter controller="HDA" driver="DirectSound" enabled="true" enabledIn="false"/>
    </Hardware>
    <StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="false" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{eab23143-54ec-4f7d-822d-a56bf90a58bb}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="1" device="0"/>
      </StorageController>
    </StorageControllers>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with VirtualBox. Is the config file just xml? Can you post a sample of the vbox file?

Comment: Yes, it's just xml